# Populate a ListView onWindowFocusChanged

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I've been having a trouble whenever I press back on my phone which would "disable" my listview rendering me unable to press it . I've found a working solution which would be to repopulate the listview onWindowFocusChanged but im having problems implementing it in this class. How would my populateListView method look like in this class?

```
public class AvailableNumbersActivity extends ListActivity // implements CallerIdListener
{
Context context;
UserController userControl;
private String[] newnumber = {""};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  context = this;

  userControl = new UserController(context);
  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) 
    {
        newnumber[0] = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        new PushNumberTask().execute(newnumber);
    }
  });

  new PullNumbersTask(context).execute();

}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private class PullNumbersTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]>
{
    private Context ctx; 

    public PullNumbersTask(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.ctx=context;
    }
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getParent());

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Henter tilgængelige numre..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return (userControl.GetNumbers());
    }


     protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) 
     {
         setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, R.layout.numbers_items, result));
         Dialog.dismiss();
     }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I understood your question completely, but if you need to refresh your `ListView`, you should save your ArrayAdapter as a member in activity and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it in your `onWindowFocusChanged` handler.